# Bad SQL Server performance when combining left outer join and inner join with multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server, performance, inner-join, multiple-columns, outer-join

Working on SQL Server 2008, I get a profound performance drop for queries like the following example - combining a left outer join with an inner join based on multiple conditions (columns):

```
select 
    table1.column_x, table2.column_y, table3.column_z
from 
    table1 
left outer join    
    table2 on table1.c1 = table2.c1
join               
    table3 on table2.d1 = table3.d1 and table2.e1 = table3.e1
```

It would harvest wrong results, but if I replace that first 'left outer join' by an inner join and leave the rest untouched, the query finishes in a matter of seconds. Same goes if I remove a condition from the (second) join, keeping only one condition there. Keeping them both in place, the query can take several minutes. I have tried putting the second condition from the second join in the where clause, but this does not improve the query time. Apart from that, I never experienced performance issues.

How comes combining these two joins results is such a performance drop? What are possible workarounds?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked query plan + maybe statistics io output, what's the difference in these cases?

Comment: What is the purpose of your join? Do you want to exclude table1 records where a table3 record does not exist (doesn't really make sense)? Or do you want to mask table2 values (but still show table1 values) where a table3 record exists?

Comment: James, good idea... I found the outer join estimates to get 30k rows, but if I leave the double conditioned inner join in place, it suddenly gets 220M rows...

Comment: Necreaux, I need the info from those tables. The inner join is required to link journal and transactional lines, as by the design of our ERP software, no unique field seems to exists, so I need those two. The outer join is there because there is no corresponding record in the joined table for every record in the query so far.

Comment: Hmm... its actually the clustered index scan on the left outer joined table that RUNS 7414 times. 7417 is the amount of rows returned. 30k rows in the outer joined table x 7414 = 220M rows for the clustered index scan--> why does that index scan run 7414 times (1 expected) when putting the double inner join in place? Prolly missing something... Still trying to rephrase the query...

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the difference in execution plans along with what indexes you have, etc. I can only speculate on why doing the things you describe are causing such vast differences in performance.

That being said, I can see something in your query that makes me question what you are trying to do but also might shed some light on why changing to an inner join makes it so much faster.  If you do an left join followed by an inner join where the inner join condition depends on a not null value from the left join it effectively makes the left join into an inner join.  Thus changing the left join to an inner join should change the execution plan, thus greatly changing the performance.

As far as removing a condition, I am guessing that some kind of table scan is happening but without knowing your indexes, table structure, etc. this is just a guess.

How to fix / work around this really depends on what you are trying to accomplish in the first place.  From what you have given us it seems like you should just change the left join to an inner join.  But since you stated that this query gives the wrong results, you may need to rethink your query altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the input, please see my comments on the question. I'm trying to rephrase my query but no luck so far.

Comment: @Sven_vD Could you post a new question with table schemas, sample data, expected results and your real query?  I have a feeling that what you are trying to accomplish can be done in a far better manner.  If you do that and link it from here I can go take a look.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it by changing the 2 condition inner join into one, just concatenating the strings... Sort of like this (see last line):

```
select 
    table1.column_x, table2.column_y, table3.column_z
from 
    table1 
left outer join    
    table2 on table1.c1 = table2.c1
join               
    table3 on table2.d1 + table2.e1 = table3.d1 + table3.e1
```

Its a workaround and I'm not particularly proud of it, but it works perfectly (client processing time from 116.448ms to 35ms). Still, I can't help but wonder why the clustered index scan started running once for every row returned just by having that double condition inner join in place. Any new ideas are offc welcome!

Thanks

Comment: can you post images of both query`s estimated  or actual plan

Comment: Bad idea, this way you'll join the record with fields 'TH' & 'E' to the record in the other table that has fields 'T' and 'HE'.